# Cannot set property 'remote_auth_s3' of undefined, when trying to implement Disqus SSO with PHP/Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, undefined, disqus

I am trying to implement Disqus Single Sign On on my site. I have been following the docs of Disqus and added all the code as described. When trying to test the SSO I get the following error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'remote_auth_s3' of undefined
```

Which comes from the following JS:

```
 <script>
  // The generated payload which should authenticate users with Disqus
     this.page.remote_auth_s3 = '{{$disqus_load}}';
     this.page.api_key = "{{env('DISQUS_PUBLIC_KEY')}}";

 </script>
```

The payload and keys are correct and tested using the Disqus api tester.

The javascript comes straight out of the Disqus documentation and should work. 
How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by putting these variables into the

```
    var disqus_config = function () {
```

The errors are now gone, but it is not working yet.